# error with com class factory

Tags: c#, .net, wia

Please all help me on this
I have created a project using C# on .NET Frame Work 4.0 and I used WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) and it was work successfully.
When I run the .exe file on another PC but I got a message saying:

"
retrieving the com class factory for component with clsid{E1C5D730-7e97-4D8A-9E42-BBAE87C205} failed due to the following error80040154
"
even both are 32 bits what could cause this error

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely that WIA is not installed on the machine; a stack trace would help to narrow down the error.

I know that WIA is not installed by default on Windows 2008 server.  You can install it by installing the Desktop Experience feature using Server Manager.

What is the configuration of the other PC?

Comment: What kind of configurations you mean??

Answer (score 0):

Try copying wiaaut.dll to the same location as the exe. It might not be a long term solution but at least it will tell you if the problem lies with trying to find the WIA library.